# How do we fire click event inside IIFE function in Jasmine JavaScript Unit test suite

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to write unit tests for the following click event inside IIFE function.

```
jQuery(function($)
{   
   $('span.select-toggle').click(function()
   {
      $i = $(this);

      if ($i.parent().find('ul.select-sub').is(':visible')) {
         $i.removeClass('fa-select-down').addClass('fa-select-right');
      } else {
         $i.removeClass('fa-select-right').addClass('fa-select-down');
      }
    });
});
```

HTML fixture file:

```
<div id="select">
    <ul class="select-stub" style="visibility :visible;">
        <span class="select-toggle" ></span>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Unit test:

```
describe('Selectmenu Expand/Collapse of a node', function () {
    beforeAll(function () {
        spyOnEvent('.select-toggle', 'click');
        $('span.select-toggle').trigger("click");
    });

    it('Should visible parent node', function () {
        expect($('.select-toggle').parent().find('ul.select-sub:visible').count()).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

But this `spyOnEvent` was not fired in the click event and failed the tests. Someone please suggest any better solution to fire click event inside IIFE function.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i use event listeners inside IIFE, maybe it can help. Note that event listeners inside IIFE should be always placed at the end of the IIFE.

```
!function() {
   function someFunction(){
      //some code
   }
   $('body').on('click', '.someClass', someFunction); //event listener
}();
```

Comment: I can't change the current behaviour of the script. I really want to fire that event listener in unit tests. So any better approach?